# XSL: How can I access a variable defined in a called template, in the calling parent scope?

Tags: xslt

My code looks something like this (deliberate simplification):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="call_me" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$inner_variable" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="call_me">
  <xsl:variable name="inner_variable" select="/*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Obviously this won't work because of the scope of the variable. My question is:
is there any way to either define the variable globally from the `call_me` template, or to access this local variable from the parent (calling template) scope?

EDIT: The variable is not a XML tree fragment, but a node-set processed by C# functions. So I really need to access the variable.

Thanks!

Comment: A global variable could be defined as `<xsl:variable name="var-name" select="/*"/>` with the `xsl:variable` placed as a child of the `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` root element of the stylesheet. I am not sure that helps but the whole question looks odd in the context of XSLT, you might want to explain what you want to achieve in terms of XML transformation and why you think you need the variables to achieve that so that we can perhaps suggest an XSLT way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a variable with the result of the called template, do:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="result">
        <xsl:call-template name="call_me" />
    </xsl:variable>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes the called template returns some kind of result, for example:

```
<xsl:template name="call_me">
    <xsl:value-of select="some-node" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly this won't do. The problem is that the variable is not a tree fragment, but a node-set processed by C# extensions. I'm going to update that in the question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a node-set processed by C# extensions". Eventually, every process in XSLT returns a result of some type. You can write the result directly to the output tree, or hold it in a variable. If you want to access the variable in the calling template, you must define it in the calling template (or higher up, as a global variable).

Comment: If you're in XSLT 1.0, then the only thing you can return from a named template is a result tree fragment. So you're scuppered. If you tell us what you are trying to achieve (what's the input and output of your transformation?) then we can probably tell you a better way of going about it.